# Cannot Connect to Remote Desktop or Remote Administrator

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a remote customer machine that will not connect with either Remote Desktop or Radmin/Remote Administrator v3.5.2.1

The machine is a fresh build of Win10 Pro 20H2 on a Xeon.
It responds to PING, and DIR \\Computer\C$ and file copies to the same.
I can PSEXEC to the machine, run CMD.EXE /k without problem.

I do not yet have access to gpedit.msc but I doubt there is a GPO on a fresh standalone build.
The machine is a WORKGROUP member.

This is the logfile from a powershell script I wrote to audit the machine.

```
   Info       Windows Version 10.0.19042.0
   Type       Client operating system
   Edition    Windows 10 Pro
   Product    Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_DM channel
   Status     License Status = 1


   Action     Checking connected networks
   Info       Connected adapter ETHERNET 2

   Action     Checking firewall profiles
   Info       Domain is Disabled
   Info       Private is Disabled
   Info       Public is Disabled

   Action     Checking registry settings
   Info       fDenyTSConnections = 0 RDP is enabled
   Info       RDGClientTransport is not present
   Info       RDP Network Level Authentication is Disabled
   Info       SMB1 protocol is Enabled

   Action     Checking RDP services
   Info       Remote Desktop Services is Running
   Info       RDP UserMode Port Redirector is Running
   Info       DCOM Server Process Launcher is Running
   Info       RPC Endpoint Mapper is Running
   Info       Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is Running

   Action     Checking listening ports
   Info       RDP port 3389 is PID=5432 in process 'svchost'
   Info       RDP port 3389 state is Listening

   Action     Checking Trusted Hosts
   Info       Trusted Hosts value is '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two separate problems working here.
#1 - Win10 host does not like the Server 2003 5.x RDP client.
Version 6.0 is the last client for Server 2003, and this is acceptable to Win10.
RDP now connects to Win10 using the v6 client.

#2 - Xfinity has a security nanny operating by default.
When they determine a threat exists, they block all incoming traffic.
So far, their automated process refuses to unblock traffic, or disable the nanny.